# How do I make a query where it filters everything that starts with a number in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model called Book with a Title Field.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null = False,blank=False)
```

Now I need a filter to get all books with titles starting with a number.

This works but how will I extend the queryset?

```
b = Book.objects.filter(title__startswith = 1).order_by('title')
```

This doesn't work

```
b = b + Book.objects.filter(title__startswith = 2).order_by('title')
```

or this

```
b.extend(Book.objects.filter(title__startswith = 2).order_by('title'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression as a query parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) to check that the a value starts with a number:

```
Book.objects.filter(title__regex=r'^\d')
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `r'^\d'` if it supposed to start with a number?